# Fastest way to count a list of words in an article using python

Tags: python, text, count, set

I am looking for how many times **all** words in a bag of words are found in an article. I am not interested in the frequency of each word but the total amount of times all of them are found in the article. I have to analyse hundreds of articles, as I retrieve them from the internet. My algorithm takes long since each article is about 800 words.

Here is what I do (where ***amount*** is the number of times the words were found in a single article, ***article*** contains a string with all the words forming the article content, and I use NLTK to tokenize.)

```
bag_of_words = tokenize(bag_of_words)
tokenized_article = tokenize(article)

occurrences = [word for word in tokenized_article
                    if word in bag_of_words]

amount = len(occurrences)
```

Where the ***tokenized_article*** looks like:

```
[u'sarajevo', u'bosnia', u'herzegovi', u'war', ...]
```

And so does the ***bag_of_words***.

I was wondering if there's any more efficient/faster way of doing it using NLTK or lambda functions, for instance.

Comment: I'm not sure how NTLK could help you here – you're doing comparisons of strings, and that's about it.

Now, there are a few ways to go about this a bit more efficiently: make `bag_of_words` a `set`, as this has constant-time membership check (instead of linear-time in the size of the list). Now, you can count the occurrences of N words in any set in O(N), which you can't beat (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a `set` for the words you are counting - a `set` has constant-time membership test and so, is faster than using a list (which has a linear-time membership test).

For example:

```
occurrences = [word for word in tokenized_article
                    if word in set(bag_of_words)]

amount = len(occurrences)
```

Some timing tests (with an artificially created list, repeated ten times):

```
In [4]: words = s.split(' ') * 10

In [5]: len(words)
Out[5]: 1060

In [6]: to_match = ['NTLK', 'all', 'long', 'I']

In [9]: def f():
   ...:     return len([word for word in words if word in to_match])

In [13]: timeit(f, number = 10000)
Out[13]: 1.0613768100738525

In [14]: set_match = set(to_match)

In [15]: def g():
    ...:     return len([word for word in words if word in set_match])

In [18]: timeit(g, number = 10000)
Out[18]: 0.6921310424804688
```

---

Some other tests:

```
In [22]: p = re.compile('|'.join(set_match))

In [23]: p
Out[23]: re.compile(r'I|all|NTLK|long')

In [24]: p = re.compile('|'.join(set_match))

In [28]: def h():
    ...:     return len(filter(p.match, words))

In [29]: timeit(h, number = 10000)
Out[29]: 2.2606470584869385
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sets for membership testing.

Another method of checking could be to count the occurrences of each word, and add the occurrence if the word exist, assuming articles contain some frequency of repeating words and if the article are not very short. Let's say
an article contain 10 "the", now we only check for membership one time instead of 10 times.

```
from collections import Counter
def f():
    return sum(c for word, c in Counter(check).items() if word in words)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the count, it's not "bag of words" anymore, but set of words. So convert your document to a `set` *if* that is really the case.

**Avoid for loops and lambda functions**, in particular nested ones. This requires a lot of *interpreter* work, and is slow. Instead, try to use optimized calls such as `intersection` (for performance, libraries such as `numpy` are also very good because they do the work in low-level C/Fortran/Cython code)

i.e.

```
count = len(bag_of_words_set.intersection( set(tokenized_article) ))
```

where `word_set` is the words you are interested in, as a `set`.

If you want a classic word count instead, use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter()
...
counter.update(tokenized_article)
```

This will count *all* words though, including those not in your list. You can try this, but it may turn out to be slower because of the loop:

```
bag_of_words_set = set(bag_of_words)
...
for w in tokenized_article:
   if w in bag_of_words_set: # use a set, not a list!
      counter[w] += 1
```

A bit more complex, but potentially faster, is the use of two `Counter`s. One total, and one for the documents.

```
doc_counter.clear()
doc_counter.update( tokenized_article )
for w in doc_counter.keys():
  if not w in bag_of_words_set: del doc_counter[w]
counter.update(doc_counter) # untested.
```

The use of a counter for the document is beneficial if you have many duplicate unwanted words, where you can save a lookup. It's also better for multithreaded operation (easier synchronization)

Comment: Thanks. The execution is clearly faster, but the amount of words counted isn't right. Also, I used len(word_set.intersection( set(document) )) because there is no attribute suck as 'intersection_size'.

Comment: This version only counts each word once per document, because that appeared to be what you described. use `from collections import Counter` rather than sets to count every occurrence.

Comment: sorry, I thought python had an optimized `intersection_size` but apparently it doesn't. Then len is a workaround, but slower. But apparently you don't want a set at that level yet anyway.